# Can we aggregate dynamic number of rows using Talend Open Studio

Tags: etl, talend

I'm a beginner in Talend Open Studio, and I'm trying to do the transformation below.

From a SQL Table that contains:

```
DeltaStock          Date 
------------------------
+50 (initial stock) J0    
+80                 J1    
-30                 J2
...                 ...
```

I want to produce this table:

```
Stock  Date
-----------
50     J0             
130    J1
100    J2 
...    ...
```

Do you think this could be possible using TOS? I thought of using tAggregateRow, but I didn't find it appropriate to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way to do this using the tMemorizeRows component but the first thought that comes to mind is to use the globalMap to store a rolling sum.

In Talend it is possible to store an object (any value or any type) in the globalMap so that it can be retrieved later on in the job. This is used automatically if you ever use a tFlowToIterate component which allows you to retrieve the values for that row that is being iterated on from the globalMap.

A very basic sample job might look like this:

[image: Sample job layout]

In this we have a tJava component that only initialises the rolling sum in the globalMap with the following code:

```java
//Initialise the rollingSum global variable
globalMap.put("rollingSum", 0);
```

After this we connect this component onSubjobOk to make sure we only carry on if we've managed to put the `rollingSum` into the globalMap.

I then provide my data using a tFixedFlowInput component which allows me to easily hardcode some values for this example job. You could easily replace this with any input. I have used your sample input data from the question:

[image: tFixedFlowInput configuration and sample data]

We then process the data using a tJavaRow which will do some transformations on the data row by row. I've used the following code which works for this example:

```java
//Initialise the operator and the value variables
String operator = "";
Integer value = 0;

//Get the current rolling sum
Integer rollingSum = (Integer) globalMap.get("rollingSum");

//Extract the operator
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([+-])([0-9]+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input_row.deltaStock);

//If we have any matches from the regular expression search then extract the operator and the value
if (m.find()) {
    operator = m.group(1);
    value = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
}

//Conditional to use the operator
if ("+".equals(operator)) {
    rollingSum += value;
} else if ("-".equals(operator)) {
    rollingSum -= value;
} else {
    System.out.println("The operator provided wasn't a + or a -");
}

//Put the new rollingSum back into the globalMap
globalMap.put("rollingSum", rollingSum);

//Output the data
output_row.stock = rollingSum;
output_row.date = input_row.date;
```

There's quite a lot going on there but basically it starts by getting the current `rollingSum` from the globalMap.

Next, it uses a regular expression to split up the `deltaStock` string into an `operator` and a `value`. From this it uses the operator provided (plus or minus) to either add the `deltaStock` to the `rollingSum` or subtract the `deltaStock` from the `rollingSum`.

After this it then adds the new `rollingSum` back into the globalMap and outputs the 2 columns of `stock` and `date` (unchanged).

In my sample job I then output the data using a tLogRow which will print the values of the data to the console. I typically select the table formatting option in it and in this case I get the following output:

```
.-----+----.
|tLogRow_8 |
|=----+---=|
|stock|date|
|=----+---=|
|50   |J0  |
|130  |J1  |
|100  |J2  |
'-----+----'
```

Which should be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in Talend Open Studio.

I attach here an image with the JOB, the content of the tJavaRow and the execution result. 
[image]

I left under the tFixedFlowInput used to simulate the input a tJDBCInput that you should use to read the data from your DB. Hopefully you can use a specific tXXXInput for your DB instead of the generic JDBC one.

Here is some simple code in the tJavaRow.

```
//Code generated according to input schema and output schema
output_row.delta = input_row.delta;
output_row.date = input_row.date;
output_row.rollingSum = 
   Integer.parseInt(globalMap.get("rollingSum").toString());

int delta = Integer.parseInt(input_row.delta);

output_row.rollingSum += delta;

// Save rolling SUM for next round
globalMap.put("rollingSum", output_row.rollingSum);
```

Beware of the exceptions in the parseInt(). You should handle them the way you feel right.
In my projects I usually have a SafeParse library that does not throws exceptions but returns a default value I can pass together with the vale to be parsed.